# Converting my PC's On/Off Status LED to a Fading LED

Tags: led, capacitor, 555

Right now the output of the LED blinks on and off when in standby. This is pretty annoying. I was looking for a way to turn this circuit into a fading LED instead.

The simplest solution possible I could think of would be a capacitor, but I want to make sure I do it correctly.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f3eyN7.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: The LED would not work with 1 V anyway.

Comment: What rate is the blinking?

Comment: I would use an op amp connected as a voltage follower to drive the LED off the capacitor's voltage.  Is it important to you that the fade be symmetrical?

Comment: @jonathanjo it's blinking at a rate of about a half second. on for a half second and off for a half second

Comment: @vir for this I don't think it matters all that much. It's purpose is just to make it less distracting and more smooth

Comment: @Uwe, the 1V is just the CircuitLab default, I believe.

Comment: @Sam that's right. It's probably more like 5v being from my PC. I can check

Comment: Why not use the simulate feature?  Change the battery into a "voltage function generator" (square wave, 2.5V amplitude with 2.5V offset, 0.5 Hz) and play with all the values until you get what you want.  (You'll also need to add a ground symbol for the simulator to work.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are unanticipated results with such an approach. First, be aware that LED current is proportional to what we see, not LED voltage...
Upon turn-on, C1 starts charging from zero volts, exponentially. C1's voltage must rise to about 3V before the (assumed WHITE) LED begins to pull current. This causes a substantial delay before light is emitted. After that, light ramps up exponentially for a short span, which is pleasing to the eye. The last portion of charging appears to the eye as nearly full brilliance.
For a disk activity light that blinks on-off rapidly, the delay would be a problem - for an on-off indicator LED, less a problem.
[image: LTspice schematic LED with parallel capacitor]
[image: LTspice transient response LED with parallel capacitor]
There is no delay for the turn-off event. LED current falls exponentially, which is pleasing to the eye.
Be aware that RC time constant might be calculated and assumed that light output would follow - this is not the case - light output *change* is much faster.

Comment: Ok. I can give that a go. I'll see how bad the ramp down is.

Comment: Here's a video of how it turned out... It almost seems like we ended up with the opposite of the simulation!

https://youtu.be/5r_UpQcqWlw

Comment: I'm going to also try some higher value caps

Comment: All you need is another resistor in series with the LED. The circuit you have built will take some time to charge the capacitor to a voltage which turns on the LED, and then it will act as a shunt regulator to hold that voltage. Removing the supply will quickly drain the capacitor to a voltage where the LED will turn off. The added resistor will control the discharge current over a longer time period.

Comment: @PStechPaul Ok, I'll try another resistor in series. what value are you thinking? 4.7k?

Comment: That would reduce the brightness quite a bit. If it's too dim, maybe try 2.2k, for both resistors.